# How to update Ubuntu Core 20 ip address?

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I just installed Ubuntu Core 20 in a Raspberry Pi 4. I followed all the steps in the Ubuntu tutorial. The network was configured using wifi with a static IP. All settings were entered correctly, however once I completed the setup and the device restarted, it showed how to login using  `ssh <SSO username>@<IP Address>`, but this didn't work. I was unable to ping the device at the address I configured.

I tried rebooting, but now it shows the following:

```
Ubuntu Core 20 on <no ip address> (tty2)
You Cannot log in until the system has an IP address. (Is there 
supposed to be a DHCP server running on your network?)

Personalize your account at https://login.ubuntu.com
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this? I tried Google, but everyone has a different problem or connected to a different interface, even entering commands. I don't have a terminal. I try to type anything it doesn't work, and I think that is not supposed to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply and question. When I boot the device for the first time I am asked to press enter and configure the network. This is following the tutorial here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-core: So, I selected the wlan0, scanned for available networks and configure the WiFi password. Then, I select the IPv4 settings and change it to manual. Set the subnet to 10.0.0.0/24, ip address to 10.0.0.200, gateway to 10.0.0.1 and name servers to 8.8.8.8. That's it, from there I select "Done" and the device reboots

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in the same situation and can't see the wifi details config file on the SDcard in any of the usual locations.

The official advice to change your network settings is to do a recovery mode startup, by holding down or repeatedly pressing the '1' key as the system boots then choose reinstall or try to use the recovery mode if you wish...

According to: https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/uc20/recovery-modes#heading--chooser

> To access the recovery chooser, start or reboot the device with the ‘1’ key held on a connected keyboard. If the chooser fails to launch, try pressing 1 repeatedly from boot. It needs to be captured by Ubuntu Core boot process.

> After the initial boot process completes, a status screen will appear showing “System mode selection triggered. Proceed to select one of the available systems and actions.”

> The following recovery functions are currently available:
>
> - Run normally: restart and run the boot process (run mode)
> - Recover: reboot into recovery mode for data retrieval
> - Reinstall: initialise the device from an onboard system image

Would love to know if you go to the bottom of this as to why a static IP assignment failed for you.